# Throttle event in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I've haven't had to look across streams in Azure Stream Analytics, but know it is within the capabilities of the tool.  I have small messages that will be entering my solution from many sources and will be passing through a function to "normalize" the data before going to its final destination in a Data Lake.  I need to have data flowing through the solution that meets certain criteria trigger a notification, but need to ensure that I am not creating too much noise in the notification, so want to limit a given combination to being sent once in a given period of time.

For an example of what I would like to do, consider a temperature example:

```
{
    Location: "Server",
    Temperature: 75
}
```

If a reading comes in with the Temperature exceeding 80, the event should be selected as output to the notifier (likely SendGrid), but *only* if the same location/temperature combination has not been output in the last hour.

The concept that most applies what I'm looking to do is react-throttle.

Can someone point me to docs that will help me understand where to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve this scenario you can use our IsFirst operator over a 1 hour period. That will ensure that only the first event in a 1 hour window will trigger a notification.

> SELECT *
>
> INTO alert
>
> FROM input
>
> WHERE ISFIRST(hour, 1) OVER (WHEN temp > 80)=1

More info on this operator [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn966248.aspx).

Let me know if you have any further question.

Thanks,

JS (Azure Stream Analytics)